# Is there a way to create .jmx version for the given input of webdriver code manually

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, jmeter, jmx

I need to research on how could we create a .jmx version of selenium web driver code(i.e., when a web driver code is given as input then it needs to create the .jmx XML of this web driver code) just want to know is there any way of creating it.

I have seen website octoperf where they are doing it similarly. I have gone through the apache JMeter documentation found about GUI and the usage of Jmeter but our intention is not to use Jmeter GUI but need to provide load testing with similar kind of api.

So any websites on this information please suggest accordingly which will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

There is a JMeter-Selenium FireFox plugin which you can replay your WebDriver test and output the JMX equivalent.

- Addon - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/jmeter/
- RedLine13 Tutorial - https://www.redline13.com/blog/selenium-jmeter-plugin-tutorial/
- RedLine13 Video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qw8gzCBO0qE

Answer (score 0):

Configure BrowserMobProxy to your selenium webdriver and it will generate .har file out of it

Use any plugin like [flood.io](https://flood.io/har2jmx) where we can convert this .har file into the jmx

but just beware when you are using the data driven , in the request data it will get hardcoded the value

Answer (score -1):

In fact [JMeter has an API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/) so you should be able to create an end-to-end JMeter test programatically even if it assumes [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/) usage.

See

- **4.3 Creating a New JMeter Test Purely in Java** chapter of the [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui)
- or [jmeter-from-code example project](https://bitbucket.org/blazemeter/jmeter-from-code)

to get started

Comment: Thank you for the help Dmitri T i will go through the API which might help and the last jmeter-from-code example project is helpful will go through it if any issues faced will get back but it helps thank you

Comment: gone through the api and want to know the usage of org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.RecordingController this is need to implement gone through all the websites to know how to use it but no help anywhere is it possible to implement the recordingController without using GUI @dmitri-t